# Default Group for new Users

Tags: centos, useradd

Is there a possibility to define a default group for new Users? I mean I define the group `testgroup` as the default usergroup and when I add `User1` and `User2`, both new Users would be in the group `testgroup` without defining this group on the `useradd` command as following?

```
# useradd -G testgroup User1
```

---

With

```
 # useradd -D
```

I get on the first line `GROUP=100`. But when I add a new User, the new user is added to a group called as the new user but not to the group with the `id=100`. For what is this definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the following line in `/etc/login.defs` to make the `GROUP` default in `/etc/default/useradd` active.

```
USERGROUPS_ENAB no
```

From `man useradd`

> ...By default, a group will also be created for the new user (see -g, -N, -U, and USERGROUPS_ENAB)...

The *why* is probably because of security thoughts. But I am sure there are already some post somewhere out there discussing this. So open the search engine of your choice and...